# MVC pass some parameter to controller from razor script

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I rendering page with some tabs with content (inside tabs) dynamicly.
So I got

```
 <div id="UpdateBlock">
        @Html.Action("GeneratorTemplate", "FormTemplate", new { id = 8 })
 </div>
```

it calls

```
 public ActionResult GeneratorTemplate(int id)
 {
   //Description desk = new Description();
   return PartialView("~/Views/FormTemplate/GeneratorTemplate.cshtml");
 }
```

I want to make something like this

```
<div id="UpdateBlock">
  @Html.Action("GeneratorTemplate", "FormTemplate", new { openedtab = getActiveTab() })
</div>

public ActionResult GeneratorTemplate(int openedtab)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/FormTemplate/GeneratorTemplate.cshtml", openedtab);
}
```

And there in partialview call `ajax` function with `openedtab` parameter. Like this

```
 var g_id = openedtab;
 function updateGenerators(g_id) {
            var g_list;

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: '/Generator/GetCurrentGenerator',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {
                     generatorNumber: g_id
                 },
                 success: function (text) {
                     w2alert(text);
                 },
                 error: function (request, status, error) {
                     alert(request.responseText);
                 }
            });
        }
```

I tried to call Js inside razor but it not works that way. How could I do what I need?
Using what I can access to data which I pass with return `PartialView("~/Views/FormTemplate/GeneratorTemplate.cshtml", openedtab);`?

Comment: You can use the '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["openedtab"]' property in a razor view to access the openedtag parameter in JavaScript...

Comment: @NeilHibbert well, it's null for some reason

Comment: OK well since MVC Wrappers run on the server   @Html.Action("GeneratorTemplate", "FormTemplate", new { openedtab = getActiveTab() }) will render HTML from that partial view with the value of openedtab being assigned to whatever getActiveTab() initially returns (which seems to be null); to refresh the content in the <div id="UpdateBlock" /> you would have to use subsequent ajax calls from the client to get new data from the server...

Comment: >`new { openedtab = getActiveTab() }`
it's just not working like that, it says that `getActiveTab()` does not exists

Comment: No it wouldn't, because it's expecting to find a Server/C# method with that name, not a Client/JavaScript one...

Comment: @NeilHibbert oh, well, but what should I do then?

Comment: Declare @Html.Action("GeneratorTemplate", "FormTemplate", new { openedtab = getActiveTab() }) using a default value to represent the first tab you want selected (e.g. 1 instead of getActiveTab()) then add an event-handler to the click/select event of the other tabs. In the event handler make an ajax call to the server (sending the index/id of the new tab you want to get data for and pass that into the partial view) then update the <div id="UpdateBlock" /> with the response from the server.

Comment: @NeilHibbert oh, could you answer with an example pls? I don't fully understand